# unable to import models: for comment

Tags: django, django-models

i'm trying to import comment models but i'm getting error while migrate

my code

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image
from django.urls import reverse

class Post(models.Model):
     title= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics')
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author= models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.title

  def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse('User-Posts-Details', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

 class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
bio = models.TextField(max_length=300)
image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg',upload_to='profile_pics')

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

def save(self):
    super().save()

    img = Image.open(self.image.path)

    if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
        output_size = (300,300)
        img.thumbnail(output_size)
        img.save(self.image.path)

 class Comments(models.Model):
     Post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='comments')
     user_id = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=True)
     comment = models.TextField()
     commented = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

the error is :- django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'userpost_comment' with primary key '1' has an invalid foreign key: userpost_comment.author_id contains a value 'sd' that does not have a co
rresponding value in auth_user.id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the migration error suggested, there is no `auther_id` against `sd` in Database. To fix that, first you need to remove your last migration file which was created when you ran `makemigrations` command.

Then, there are two options:

**1.** Change the user field to make it null-able:

```
class Comments(models.Model):
     post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='comments')
     user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, default=None)
```

Then you can run `makemigrations` and `migrate` command. But downside of this solution is it will make user field nullable.

**2.** Add a default value in `user`to an integer, which is an existing primary key from your database:

```
class Comments(models.Model):
     post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='comments')
     user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
```

Then run `makemigrations` and `migrate` to add changes in database.